# Encoded JWT using PKCS8 RSA256 algorithm on jwt.io but not in application

Tags: swift, jwt

I has a problem when I try to implementing JWT in swift 4.
I use JWT library from jwt.io.
I am trying to encrypt the payload with the PKCS8 pem filetype and RSA256 algorithm  certificate.
but always error with message  "The operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error -50 - RSA private key creation from data failed)"

can someone help me?

code:

```
let payload: [AnyHashable:Any] = ["payload":"hiden_information"]
let algorithmName = "RS256"
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "priv", ofType: "pem")
let privateKeySecretData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
let privateKey = String(data: privateKeySecretData!, encoding: .utf8)!

let signDataHolder: JWTAlgorithmRSFamilyDataHolder =  JWTAlgorithmRSFamilyDataHolder()
 _ = signDataHolder.keyExtractorType(JWTCryptoKeyExtractor.privateKeyWithPEMBase64().type)
_ = signDataHolder.algorithmName(algorithmName)
_ = signDataHolder.secret(privateKey)

let signBuilder : JWTEncodingBuilder = JWTEncodingBuilder.encodePayload(payload)
_ = signBuilder.addHolder(signDataHolder)

let signResult = signBuilder.result
        if ((signResult?.successResult) != nil) {
            print(signResult!.successResult.encoded)
        } else {
            print(signResult?.errorResult.error.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT version 3.0.0.-beta7 not suported PKCS8.
i use PKCS1 with RSA256 and it worked!

```
 func encryptPayload(payload:[AnyHashable:Any])->String?
{
    var resultStr: String?

    var publicKeyCrypto: JWTCryptoKeyProtocol? = nil
    do {
        publicKeyCrypto = try JWTCryptoKeyPublic(pemEncoded: AppConstant.Scurity.publicKey, parameters: nil)
    }
    catch {
        NSLog("error: \(error)")
    }

    guard let theCrypto = publicKeyCrypto else {
        return nil
    }

    do {

        let privateKeyCrypto = try JWTCryptoKeyPrivate(pemEncoded: privateKey, parameters: nil)

        guard let holder = JWTAlgorithmRSFamilyDataHolder().signKey(privateKeyCrypto)?.secretData(AppConstant.Scurity.privateKey.data(using: .utf8))?.algorithmName(JWTAlgorithmNameRS256) else {return nil}

        let headers : [AnyHashable:Any] = ["alg": "RS256","typ": "JWT"]

        guard let encoding = JWTEncodingBuilder.encodePayload(payload).headers(headers)?.addHolder(holder) else {return nil}

        let result = encoding.result

        print(result?.successResult?.encoded ?? "Encoding failed")
        print(result?.errorResult?.error ?? "No encoding error")

        let verifyDataHolder = JWTAlgorithmRSFamilyDataHolder().signKey(theCrypto)?.secretData(publicKey.data(using: .utf8)!)?.algorithmName(JWTAlgorithmNameRS256)

        let verifyResult = JWTDecodingBuilder.decodeMessage(result?.successResult?.encoded).addHolder(verifyDataHolder)?.result

        if verifyResult?.successResult != nil, let result = verifyResult?.successResult.encoded {
            print("Verification successful, result: \(result)")
        } else {
            print("Verification error: \(verifyResult!.errorResult.error)")
        }
        resultStr = result?.successResult.encoded
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return resultStr
}
```